# Why does $P[X \leq p_{k/100}] = \frac{k}{100}$ work?

Tags: statistics

I am a student studying an introductory course in statistics. We have recently covered percentiles and the following equation was given to us without explanation:
$$P\left[X \leq p_{\frac{k}{100}}\right] = \frac{k}{100}$$
I'm wondering how the $k$th percentile is represented by  the point $p_{\frac{k}{100}}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percentiles are defined in terms of multiples of $1/100$ for which your distribution has that probability of being less than or equal to the percentile value. Your equation suggests that $p_{k/100}$ is the $k$th percentile. If that is true, then the probability of $X \leq p_{k/100}$ is indeed $k/100$, by definition of the percentile. The value of $p_{k/100}$ will be some real number, such that the probability of getting the $k$th percentile is equal to the probability that your random variable $X$ is less than or equal to $p_{k/100}$, for which the probability is $k$%.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed and well explained answer. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It works because $p_{k/100}$ is defined to be the value of the random variable that makes it work.

As you slide $c$ to the right, the value of $P[X \leq c]$ increases from $0$ to $1$, so there will be some point at which it assumes exactly the prescribed value $k/100$--that value of $c$ is then what $p_{k/100}$ is.

This is somewhat simplified since there could be flat spots or jumps in the distribution, but that's the basic idea.

Specifically, if $F_X$ is the cumulative density function (CDF), then $p_t$ is precisely $F_X^{-1}(t)$. If $F_X$ is not 1-1 or onto $[0,1]$, then special considerations must be made for some percentiles (they are ambiguous or ill-defined).

Comment: Thanks for the intuitive answer. However, I was looking for something more detailed.

Comment: @wonggr: Note my additional comment in the answer. This is not just intuitive, it is quite specific.

Comment: Another great answer, thank you again.